# Is Azure Spatial Anchors support Holographic Remoting with Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, azure-spatial-anchors

[HoloLens 2 Tutorial Azure Spatial Anchors](https://youtu.be/_SVTIbp8vro)

When I saw the author of this article responded that "It work on a PC with Holographic Remoting App",
then I used Holographic Remoting with Play mode and I get a "DllNotFoundException: AzureSpatialAnchors" error.

Is there a message I missed?
If it's not supported, can it only be released on Hololens2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link to the official documentation on [Azure spatial anchors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/). There is no reference in the official documentation to support the claim that you can run the app on PC with Holographic Remoting App.

You might still need the HoloLens device to test the app you have developed. Here are a couple of resources that will guide on developing a HoloLens solution

1. [Run the sample app: HoloLens - Unity (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/quickstarts/get-started-unity-hololens?tabs=azure-portal)
2. [create a new HoloLens Unity app using Azure Spatial Anchors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/tutorials/tutorial-new-unity-hololens-app?tabs=azure-portal)

However, if you plan to test Azure spatial anchors on a different device other than HoloLens, the documentation provides tutorials on how to get started with spatial anchors and build Android or iOS applications through Unity. Refer the below image for different resources available on the [Azure spatial anchors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/)
[image]

Comment: I the version history for Holographic Remoting it says "Improved support for Azure Spatial Anchors" for version 2.8.1, so it should work, but I tried and could not get it working.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/native/holographic-remoting-version-history#version-281-july-6-2022-

Comment: It should be supported in the newest version https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples/releases/tag/v2.14.1